# ScrollBar in DataGridView

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a winform in vs2008 that contains a DataGridView. The datagrid contains a list with several columns. These are fixed width, exept one that I have set up to take whatever space is left and fill the width of the view. The winform is resizeable in all directions.

The issue I am trying to solve is that when I increase the vertical size of the window the scrollbar disappears and the columns snap to the right to fill the extra space. What I would like to happen is that the vertical scrollBar never disappears. Setting ScrollBars to vertical in the properties of the DataGridView does not do this.

Is this at all possible to achieve? And, if so, how do I get the vertical scrollbar to always be visible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try subclassing the DataGridView and handling the VerticalScrollBar's VisibleChanged event. You should be able to set the Visible property to True in there, overriding the default behaviour.

Something like this, I think...

```
public class SubclassedDataGridView : DataGridView
    {
        public SubclassedDataGridView (): base()
        {
            VerticalScrollBar.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(VerticalScrollBar_VisibleChanged);
        }

        void VerticalScrollBar_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VerticalScrollBar.Visible = true;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Ok... So I understand what you're doing here, however I have allready tried setting the scrollbar visible in the DataGridView. Why should this make it behave any differently?

Comment: Because you're overriding the VisibleChanged event. If you set the scrollbar visible on load, but then it resizes itself and decides it doesn't need a vertical scrollbar after all, it will disappear, but this event will fire, whereupon you override the property and (hopefully) voila!

Comment: Y'welcome! I've had a bit of a play and it does seem to work, remaining visible but greyed out when it's not needed, but it looks like you might have to set the scrollbar's height yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't really work for me. I've got a StackOverflowException, since setting the Visibility fires another VisibleChanged event. And we aren't actually overriding any event, we are just subscribing an additional callback to this event. The original callbacks subscribed by the base class are still called AFTER the derived class' callback. I didn't find a way to mark this event as 'handled' too.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, (re)sorting the grid helped. Try sth like this:

```
 if (gridName.SortedColumn == null)
   gridName.Sort(gridNameColumns[columnName],ListSortDirection.Ascending);
 else
 {
    ListSortDirection dir;
    if (gridName.SortOrder == SortOrder.Descending) 
       dir = ListSortDirection.Descending;
    else dir = ListSortDirection.Ascending;

    gridName.Sort(gridName.SortedColumn, dir);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibility is to trigger the event of when the scrollbar is disapearing so you can prevent the event and stop it.

Comment: This answer is low quality and it should be written as comment, so once you will gain enough reputation (`50 rep`), it will be better to write this as comment

Comment: Requires example so that it would be easily to understand what you mean by that.