# DatagridView does not show horizontal scrollbar

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagridview, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I'm using Visual Studio 2008.
I have a DatagridView which contains four columns named "Visibility", "Tipe","Name","Info".
All the column header texts are entirely visible but the texts inside the cells of the last column
are not entirely visible. I want an horizontal scrollbar to see all these texts.
The DatagridView is docked to fill to a panel and the property ScrollBars is set to Both.
I see the vertical scrollbar but not the horizontal scrollbar. I've tryed to use this suggestion like this: 
[ScrollBar in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472563/scrollbar-in-datagridview/472818#472818)
or to set MinimumSize of the DatagridView but without getting any positive results.

[image: Properties of my datagridview]

How can I display the horizontal scrollbar?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the column must have a frozen property set to true, try setting it to false

Comment: @MartinaLabMath can you please tell how you disabled frozen property?

Comment: dataGridView1.Columns["columnname"].Frozen = false;

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your Frozen column property is set to true. This was I believe an option in vs2008. This will stop the horizontal scrollbar from showing.

Comment: @MartinaLabMath If you hold ctrl and scroll mousewheel do the columns move? Could it actually be there but hidden under something else?

Comment: It works using the Frozen property, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Fill mode and frozen =false does not work for me.
Set Fill to AllCells and frozen was defaulted set to false works (VS 2015).