# Grid in a tab page page, scrollbars aren't visible

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my grid control anchored to the tab page, but I want the control and the scrollbars to fit in the visible size of the tabpage:

```
_grid = new DataGridView
 {
    Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left
  | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right,
    DataSource = _bindingSource,
 };

 _grid.CellValueChanged += _grid_CellValueChanged;
 _grid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
 tabPage.Controls.Add(_grid);
```

I can't see the scrollbars on screen.

Comment: You can use `Dock` property of your `DataGridView` and set it to `DockStyle.Fill`.

Comment: See [ScrollBar in DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/472563/719186)

Comment: @Reza - Doc worked perfectly thanks.

Comment: @JL. You're welcome :)